# asp.net RequiredFieldValidators with same validation group do not fire at same time

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, validation

I have a aspx usercontrol with 6-12 required field validators.  When I click the submit button with the same validation group as the validators, only some of the validators show thier error message, then once those have been corrected and I click the button again, the other validators show thier message.  This is quite confusing.

Here is the simplified markup for two of the textboxes (in context) and the button that is tied to the validation group.

```
<%-- PRODUCT DETAIL --------------------------------------------------- --%>
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion="">
    <dd>
        <a href="#PanelProductDetail">Product Detail</a>
        <div id="PanelProductDetail" class="content active">
            <fieldset>
                <%--<legend>Product Detail</legend>--%>
                <div class="row">
                    <%-- NAME --------------------------------------------------- --%>
                    <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
                        <label>
                            Product Name  <small>Required</small>
                            <asp:TextBox id="tbName" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvName" ControlToValidate="tbName" 
                                Text="Please add a product Name" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="AddProduct" 
                                display="Dynamic"  />
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>


<%-- PRODUCT PRICING AND INVENTORY --------------------------------------------------- --%>
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion="">
    <dd>
        <a href="#PanelProductPricing">Product Pricing and Inventory</a>
        <div id="PanelProductPricing" class="content active">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <%-- PRICE ------------------------------------------%>
                    <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns collapse">
                        <div class="row collapse">
                            <label>Price  <small>Required</small></label>
                            <div class="small-2 columns">
                                <span class="prefix">$</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-10 columns">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPrice" placeholder="Retail Price" />
                            </div>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvPrice" ControlToValidate="tbPrice" Display="Dynamic" 
                                Text="Please enter a price" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="AddProduct" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexvPrice" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPrice" Text="Invalid value for price"
                                ValidationExpression="^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$" 
                                ValidationGroup="AddProduct" CssClass="error" 
                                display="Dynamic" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Add Product" CssClass="button postfix" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddProduct" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### What Happens (summary)

In this sample the tbPrice gets its error message upon the first click of the button, and only once I have entered a value in the textbox and then click the submit button again does the tbName validator show it's error.

### What I have tried

1. I thought there might be a JS conflict so I removed the wrapping
   accordian markup - that did not solve it
2. I tried changing the order the controls appear in the markup - no
   help
3. I tries removing the display=dynamic - no help

### Question

Can someone help me figure out why only some validators get called on the first click of the button and then the remaining get called after the errors are fixed fro the first validators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that if some validators use Display="Dynamic" and some don't they validate at different times.  Once I put Display="Dynamic" in all the validators they fired at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very strange,

**The Simple answer is :**

> Validation control rendering flow  first call requirefieldvalidator, then range validator, then ...... 
>   So when you click the button, first call requirefieldvalidator

***You have used two validation controls for one input field***

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvPrice" ControlToValidate="tbPrice" Display="Dynamic" 
                                Text="Please enter a price" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="AddProduct" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexvPrice" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPrice" Text="Invalid value for price"
                                ValidationExpression="^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$" 
                                ValidationGroup="AddProduct" CssClass="error" 
                                display="Dynamic" />
```

**1) asp:RequiredFieldValidator**

**2)asp:RegularExpressionValidator**

> All RequiredFieldValidator fired first When you click the button, Once the RequiredFieldValidator is false, then the RegularExpressionValidator will call.

So please check and sure if the RegularExpressionValidator fired in secon button click???? and refer this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: your description is accurate, but it does not address the same type of validator firing at different times. thanks though